# Is it possible to change key bindings via an options menu with ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, menu

I am fairly new to actionscript and flash as a whole so I had a question about some of the functionality of the code. Is it at all possible to change the key bindings via a button that would display what keys are currently being used to move an object?

The main reason why I am asking this is because i am making a platformer and I would like to provide the ability to change what current keyboard inputs are used to make a character move. Similar to other games that provide the ability to edit a players controls to a more comfortable layout. I also would like to provide a defaulted keyboard layout and have it setup in the options menu to show what current keys are being used to a specific action.

For instance, left on the keyboard would be default for moving left but let's say i want to change it to A instead. I would want to be able to change it to that or provide that kind of functionality.

I am not sure where to begin with this or if it is even possible. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I would also like to retain these options as long as the game is open or even store them to the file if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is functionality you will have to program yourself. It should be fairly simple to listen for the user to press a key, and save the unique [keyCode](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/KeyboardEvent.html#keyCode) for the key they pressed to a variable. Then when a key is pressed, you can check it against the saved key code. As for saving these settings, you can use a [Local Shared Object](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html).

Here is a basic overview. Say you have the following object.

```
var keys:Object = {
    left: Keyboard.LEFT,
    right: Keyboard.RIGHT,
    up: Keyboard.UP,
    down: Keyboard.DOWN
};
```

If you wanted to customize the up arrow, you could add the following code after some user input (i.e. a button click).

```
addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDown);
function keyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    keys.up = e.keyCode;
}
```

Then anywhere you want to test if the up keyCode was pressed, you can do the following.

```
if(keys.up == e.keyCode)
{
    //Customized up key pressed.
}
```